# Confirm box is not working in javascript validation

Tags: javascript

I am working on a form with java script validation.I have a problem with the validation.The confirm box is not working at a particular instance.My code is

```
if ( ( frm_update_announcement.sublink[0].checked == true ))
{
    if ((document.getElementById('captionurl').value.trim()=="") && document.getElementById("captionfile").files.length == 0 ) )
    {       
        if (document.getElementById('olddocument').value.trim()=="")
        {
            alert("Enter a url/upload a file");
            document.getElementById('captionurl').focus();
            return false;
        }
    }       
}
if ( ( frm_update_announcement.sublink[1].checked == true ))
{
    for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
    {
        if (document.getElementById('attachment_caption' + i).value.trim()!="") 
        {
            if ((document.getElementById('url'+i).value.trim()=="") && (document.getElementById("document"+i).files.length == 0 ) )
            {
                alert("Add url/file with caption");
                document.getElementById('url'+i).focus();
                return false;   
            }                             
        }
    }         
}
if (confirm("Do you want to update the announcement") == true) 
{
    return true;
} else 
{
    return false;
}
```

mY HTML is

```
<label>
 <input type="radio" name="sublink" id="id_radio2" value="0" <?php if($announcements_details['detail_type']=="0") echo' checked="checked"'?> >&nbsp;Add attachment to title</input>
 </label>
<div class="col-md-4">      
<label> 
<input type="radio" name="sublink" id="id_radio1"  value="1" <?php if($announcements_details['detail_type']=="1") echo' checked="checked"'?> >&nbsp;Add new sublinks</input>
</label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">      
<label>
<input   type="radio" name="sublink" id="id_radio3" value="2" <?php if($announcements_details['detail_type']=="2") echo' checked="checked"'?>>&nbsp;None
</label>
```

when the condition frm_update_announcement.sublink[1].checked  becomes true the confirm box is not showing up.that's the problem.But the alert box inside that function is showing correctly.Please help me.Thanks
And let me add i have found the problem is in **if((document.getElementById('url'+i).value.trim()=="") && (document.getElementById("document"+i).files.length == 0 ) )**

Comment: If either "Enter url/file" alert is displayed, "return false" will stop the rest of the method from running, including your confirm dialog. Only when all the data is correct will the confirm dialog appear.

Comment: if i didn't return false the form will be submitted